# Не удается передать переменные внутрь функции phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Задача - пройтись в цикле по всем div-ам со страницы и сделать их скриншоты, страница processing.php уже заранее заготовлена и там есть все div-ы. Единственное адекватное по качеству картинки решение удалось найти на phantomjs:

```
function takescreen(i, j) { 
var page = require('webpage').create();


page.open('http://forvk.ru:8888/scripts/forms/processing.php', function() {
  // being the actual size of the headless browser
  page.viewportSize = { width: 5000, height: 10000 };


  var clipRect = page.evaluate(function {
    return document.querySelector(".div"+i+"_"+j).getBoundingClientRect(); //Здесь не видит переменные i и j
  });

  page.clipRect = {
    top:    clipRect.top,
    left:   clipRect.left,
    width:  clipRect.width,
    height: clipRect.height
  };

  page.render(i+'_'+j+'.png'); //Здесь все хорошо работает
  phantom.exit();
});
}

takescreen(0,1);
```

Проблема в том, что, когда я запускаю takescreen(2,3) (из этих параметров в дальнейшем формируется название div-а, например div2_3), то параметры i и j ни в какую не хотят передаваться внутрь блока кода:

```
var clipRect = page.evaluate(function {
    return document.querySelector(".div"+i+"_"+j).getBoundingClientRect(); //Здесь не видит переменные i и j
  });
```

хотя, насколько я понимаю, i и j должны быть видны из этой самой функции function()

Вот такой код, без i и j работает хорошо:

```
var clipRect = page.evaluate(function {
    return document.querySelector(".div"+1+"_"+2).getBoundingClientRect(); //Здесь не видит переменные i и j
  });
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы получилось передать внутрь эти параметры, возможно какое-либо альтернативное решение?

Answer (score 2):

В [документации](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) к `evaluate` написано, что аргумены в коллбэк метода `evaluate` можно передать, передав их в метод 'evaluate` как дополнительные аргументы после коллбэка.

Проще будет объяснить на примере:

```
var clipRect = page.evaluate(function (i, j) { // Принимаем аргументы
  return document.querySelector(".div"+i+"_"+j).getBoundingClientRect();
}, i, j); // Передаем аргументы
```